# Powershell: multi-parameters validation

Tags: powershell

I've a **Powershell** function as follows:

```
function myfunct {

    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="p1")]
        [string] $p1,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="p21")]
        [string] $p21,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="p22")]
        [string] $p22
    )

    # ...

}
```

This script accepts two configurations of parameters:

1. By specifying the value of `p1` : `p1 and [not (p21 and p22)]`
2. By specifying the value of `p21` and `p22` : `(not p1) and (p21 and p22)`

Now, I would like to check their mutual exclusivity. By reading the article **[PowerShell V2: ParameterSets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets.aspx)** on MSDN, I found an example about how to properly use the value of `$PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName` in order to check the specified parameter:

```
function test-param 
{ 
param( 
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="p1",Position=0)] 
[DateTime] 
$d, 

[Parameter(ParameterSetName="p2", Position=0)] 
[int] 
$i 
) 
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) 
    { 
    "p1"  { Write-Host $d; break} 
    "p2"  { Write-Host $i; break} 
    } 
}
```

According to the the example above, `$PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName` returns the value of a single parameter, but in my second configuration I need to know if `p21` and `p22` have been inserted (and if `p1` is empty, of course).

Is there a way to perform the parameter validation as desired? If yes, how?

Comment: You created three parameter sets but it looks like you meant to create only two.

Comment: I would like to create two configurations, but the second one needs two parameters.

Comment: Yes, what's the issue? Call the sets "p1" and "p2" or whatever. Add two parameters to the second parameter set.

Comment: Do you talking about something like that: `myscript -conf2 p21value p22value`?

Comment: I'll make an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Test(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ID")] [int]$ID,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Name")] [string]$Name,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Name")] [string]$Path
) {
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'ID' {
            "ID: $ID"
        }
        'Name' {
            "Name: $Name    Path: $Path"
        }
    }
}
```

You can additionally make some parameters mandatory with `Mandatory=$true` if you want.

There is no need to check the "mutual exclusivity". PowerShell does that for you - that's why you are defining parameter sets in the first place.